# issues with user-defined methods java

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

I have a number of issues here, first off, the code will not compile:

I'm trying to use user-defined methods for the first time and (as you can see) I'm having some trouble.

The assignment:
Write a java class with the following two user-defined methods:
Write a value-returning method named isVowel, that returns the boolean value true if a given character is a vowel, and otherwise returns the boolean value false.
Write a value-returning method named reverseDigit, that takes an int (integer) as a parameter and returns the number with its digits reversed. For example, calling reverseDigit(12345) returns the int value of 54321.
Write the main method for this class to test the above two user-defined methods.
Some things to think about:
What is the data type of the parameter passed to the isVowel method?
The isVowel method needs some conditional logic to make this decision, first pass at implementing this might be to write to test for an explicit vowel.
For the reverseDigit method, there's a couple of different ways you might want to think about doing this. One might be to convert the passed int value to a String first and then build the reverse of that String which can then be converted to an int. Look at Integer and String class API. Another means to do this could be using a purely mathematical approach.

Any tips or assistance in getting these methods to work and compile would be greatly appreciated.

These are the errors:

```
14 errors found:
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 21]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:21: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 25]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:25: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 26]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:26: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 27]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:27: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 31]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:31: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 32]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:32: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 33]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:33: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 35]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:35: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 38]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:38: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 39]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:39: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 42]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:42: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 43]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:43: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 44]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:44: class, interface, or enum expected
File: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java  [line: 46]
Error: /Users/gcaruso/Documents/CISS 110/Module 3/Module 4/In_Class_Module_8.java:46: class, interface, or enum expected
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class In_Class_Module_8 {
  public static void main(String[] args){

  }

  public static boolean isVowel(String word){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char vowels;
    System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
    vowels = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    if (word.length()!=1) return false;
    char vowels=word.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    if(vowels== 'a'|| vowels =='e' || vowels=='i'|| vowels == 'o' ||  vowels == 'u'){
      return true;
    } 
    return false;
  }
}

public static void reverseInteger() {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.print( "Enter an integer (-1 to exit): " );
  int number = keyboard.nextInt();
  while ( number != -1 ) {
    System.out.printf( "%d reversed is %d\n",
        number, reverseDigits( number ) );
    System.out.print( "Enter an integer (-1 to exit): " );
        number = keyboard.nextInt();
  }
}

public int reverseDigits( int number ) {
  int reverseNumber = 0;
  int placeValue;
  while ( number > 0 ) {
    placeValue = number % 10;
    number = number / 10;
    reverseNumber = reverseNumber * 10 + placeValue;
  }
  return reverseNumber;
}
}

public class Module8Test {
  public static void main( String args[] ) {
    Reverse application = new Reverse();
    application.reverseInteger();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tired using a sane formatting? Maybe then wild parentheses would be easier to spot.

Comment: You would spot the errors easily if your code was indented. Indent your code. All the IDEs can do it with a single keyboard shortcut

Comment: Edited for consistent indentation and style.  (Two-space indentation because that's mostly what the code used already).

Comment: Note that I would normally suppose that a method to determine whether "a given character is a vowel" would accept the character to be tested as an argument, and test just that character.  At least, that's how *I* interpret the specification.

Comment: After all these things .. also fix the convention of your class names
In_Class_Module_8  is not a Java class name according to Conventions.. It would look more like InClassModule8 and it will be representative of what this class actually represents

Comment: Could you at please at least upvote my answer since it was helpful to you to get you down to way less compiler errors? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is ridden with errors..

1) you are defining  the variable called vowels two times..

2) you are invoking a invoking a non static method in a static method.

3) problems with brackets.

Most important you have not given reverse class.

Note: If  you want us to help you, please format your code properly. That will make it easier for all.

Answer (score 1):

You have two }

```
}
}
```

and you are closing the class before the next method `reverseInteger()` that is outside of the class - fix your indentation so it is clear what you have done wrong ;)

**Update:** You have two public classes in the same file! This is not allowed - Separate them in two files with file names exactly their respective class names.

**Update 2:** Also you don't need an empty main method in each class. Only where you start your program

**Update 3:** You need a separate class Reverse for this to work that contains a non-static reverseInteger() method for this to work.. assuming that you will be calling that through instance of Class Reverse.. otherwise just use the In_Class_Module_8.reverseInteger().

Comment: Why would a non-static `reverseInteger()` method be needed or wanted?  Other than that the code is trying to use one, of course.  It looks like it wants instead to just invoke `In_Class_Module_8.reverseInteger()` (i.e. a static method, on the correct class).

Comment: I mean the way it is being called in the original code through Reverse object. Although this is allowed it should be called through the class name. The code doesn't make much sense either way. So whatever you say I agree with.